# Remove columns in data grid by chechkbox

Tags: c#

I have data grid with this code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //loadGrid(); 
    this.dataGridView2.Columns.Add("c1", "???");

    this.dataGridView2.Columns.Add("c2", "?????");
}
```

I use `Button` and `CheckListBox` for remove columns in data grid with this code:

```
private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in MyDataGridView.Columns)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(column.HeaderText, column.Visible);
        checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var selectedItem = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                MyDataGridView.Columns[selectedItem].Visible = ee.NewValue == CheckState.Checked;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When run this I have an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks.

Comment: A. Use your debugger B. You haven't shown us where this is even happening (we're supposed to guess?) C. Even if you did, there doesn't appear to be enough code here to even figure out why D. What does "when run" mean? When you click the button or when the form loads?

Answer (score 0):

In your Form2_Load code you are populating "dataGridView2"

```
this.dataGridView2.Columns.Add("c1", "???");

this.dataGridView2.Columns.Add("c2", "?????");
```

But in btnSelect_Click you are attempting to Iterate over MyDataGridView, in you code above i dont see MyDataGridView used anywhere. Maybe you copied and pasted this code from somewhere and forgot to change MyDataGridView to the datagridview name which is actually on your form dataGridView2? Revised below...

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView2.Columns)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(column.HeaderText, column.Visible);
    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var selectedItem = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dataGridView2.Columns[selectedItem].Visible = ee.NewValue == CheckState.Checked;
        }
    };
}
```

}